# Non-mapped field is valid whilst it is required and empty

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-3.2

I have a field which is non-mapped and required.

```
$builder->add('termsAndConditions', CheckboxType::class, [
    'required' => true,
    'mapped' => false,
    'attr' => [
        'class' => 'c-custom-option',
    ],
]);
```

Clientside validation will throw an error when empty, but serverside says it's valid. Currently i do an extra check on form submission `$form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid() && $form->get('termsAndConditions')->getData()==true` but the form->isValid() method shouldn't return true in my opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#required):

*If true, an HTML5 required attribute will be rendered. The corresponding label will also render with a required class.*

*This is superficial and independent from validation. At best, if you let Symfony guess your field type, then the value of this option will be guessed from your validation information.*

So, as you can see, it's only about client side validation.